# Get value from table with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I've already read some answers here but it keeps giving me undefined or blank alerts.

So I've got this PHP code and whenever I click in one of the stars I want JQUERY to get the value from "div class="rating-stars".

This was the last I used. It displays a blank alert...

```
    var pairing =  $(this).closest('td').find('.rating-stars').val();

  alert (pairing);
```

How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

```
 echo'</td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="rating-stars" value="'.$row["pairing"].'">
                        <div id="stars">
                        <span class="star" title="Ó mãe! Que mal foi que eu te fiz?" data-value="1">
                          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="star" title="Mais valia não ter aberto a garrafa!" data-value="2">
                          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="star" title="Assim, assim…" data-value="3">
                          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="star" title="Eu sabia! A mãe nunca se engana!" data-value="4">
                          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="star" title="És a melhor mãe do mundo!" data-value="5">
                          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                        </td>                                                                                       
                     </tr>';
```

Comment: Got it:  var pairing = $(this).closest('td').find('.rating-stars').attr("value");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.val()` on DIVs, only input elements. Use a `data-XXX` attribute, and read it with jQuery `.data()`.

```
echo'</td>
        <td>
        <div class="rating-stars" data-stars="'.$row["pairing"].'">
        <div id="stars">
        <span class="star" title="Ó mãe! Que mal foi que eu te fiz?" data-value="1">
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star" title="Mais valia não ter aberto a garrafa!" data-value="2">
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star" title="Assim, assim…" data-value="3">
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star" title="Eu sabia! A mãe nunca se engana!" data-value="4">
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star" title="És a melhor mãe do mundo!" data-value="5">
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        </td>                                                                                       
</tr>';
```

Then:

```
var pairing =  $(this).closest('td').find('.rating-stars').data("stars");
```

Comment: It was working but I fixed it with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't add nonstandard attributes.